# PHPUnit mock faster and don't repeat the code

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit, prophecy

I like to ask you about your practice of writing unit test, how to mock object and don't repeat the code?

I am using Symfony2 framework and for example I have many bundles with custom validators. When me and the rest of my team writing unit test we repeat the code of mocking Constraint, ExecutionContext, ConstraintViolationBuilderInterface. I know that we can create trait or abstract class or something else where we can store code responsible for mocking but before I will start doing this I like to know your best practices.

My first idea was to create a class/trait which will store for example mock of all repositories. Example:

```
class MockRepositoryHelper extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function getUserRepositoryMock()
    {
        return $this->prophesize(UserRepository::class);
    }

    // next repositories getters
}
```

and then use this code in real test case:

```
class EmailValidator extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    private $mockRepositoryHelper;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->mockRepositoryHelper = new MockRepositoryHelper();
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function it_should_find_user()
    {
        $userRepository = $this->mockRepositoryHelper->getUserReposioryMock();
        $userRepository->findUser(Argument::type('string'))->willReturn(null);

        // rest of the test
    }
}
```

Of course this is only pseudo code what I imagined, my first thought. What are yours ideas?

Basically I am asking how to write unit test faster and don't repeat the code?

Comment: TBH I don't see any benefit in `MockRepositoryHelper` - you just proxy the call to Prophecy. Of course, I understand, that real examples will be more complex. But it seems to me, that the idea of generalizing the mocking process in a separate class is kinda wrong, because each mock will be configured individually with regards to requirements of the test, i.e you cannot write `willReturn(null)` for all tests.

Comment: What you can extract (and we do that) is custom assertions. For instance, for testing API controllers we have a trait with assertions like `assertJSONResponse`, `assertErrorStructure` that are tailored for our needs.